# C slower than Java: why?

Tags: java, c, performance, optimization

I quickly wrote a **C** program extracting the **i-th line** of a set of **gzipped** files (containing about 500,000 lines). Here is my C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <zlib.h>

/* compilation:
gcc  -o linesbyindex -Wall -O3 linesbyindex.c -lz
*/
#define MY_BUFFER_SIZE 10000000
static void extract(long int index,const char* filename)
   {
   char buffer[MY_BUFFER_SIZE];
   long int curr=1;
   gzFile in=gzopen (filename, "rb");
   if(in==NULL)
       {
       fprintf(stderr,"Cannot open \"%s\" %s.\n",filename,strerror(errno));
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);              }
   while(gzread(in,buffer,MY_BUFFER_SIZE)!=-1 && curr<=index)
       {
       char* p=buffer;
       while(*p!=0)
           {
           if(curr==index)
               {
               fputc(*p,stdout);
               }
           if(*p=='\n')
               {
               ++curr;
               if(curr>index) break;
               }
           p++;
           }
       }
   gzclose(in);
   if(curr<index)
       {
       fprintf(stderr,"Not enough lines in %s (%ld)\n",filename,curr);
       }
   }

int main(int argc,char** argv)
   {
   int optind=2;
   char* p2;
   long int count=0;
   if(argc<3)
       {
       fprintf(stderr,"Usage: %s (count) files...\n",argv[0]);
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }
   count=strtol(argv[1],&p2,10);
   if(count<1 || *p2!=0)
       {
       fprintf(stderr,"bad number %s\n",argv[1]);
       return EXIT_SUCCESS;
       }
   while(optind< argc)
       {
       extract(count,argv[optind]);
       ++optind;
       }
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
   }
```

As a test, I wrote the following equivalent code in java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;

public class GetLineByIndex{
   private int index;

   public GetLineByIndex(int count){
       this.index=count;
   }

   private String extract(File file) throws IOException
       {
       long curr=1;
       byte buffer[]=new byte[2048];
       StringBuilder line=null;
       InputStream in=null;
       if(file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".gz")){
           in= (new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));
       }else{
           in= (new FileInputStream(file));
       }
             int nRead=0;
       while((nRead=in.read(buffer))!=-1)
           {
           int i=0;
           while(i<nRead)
               {
               if(buffer[i]=='\n')
                   {
                   ++curr;
                   if(curr>this.index) break;
                                     }
               else if(curr==this.index)
                   {
                   if(line==null) line=new StringBuilder(500);
                   line.append((char)buffer[i]);
                   }
               i++;
               }
           if(curr>this.index) break;
           }
       in.close();
       return (line==null?null:line.toString());
       }

   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
       int optind=1;
       if(args.length<2){
           System.err.println("Usage: program (count) files...\n");
           return;
       }
       GetLineByIndex app=new GetLineByIndex(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));

       while(optind < args.length)
           {
           String line=app.extract(new File(args[optind]));
           if(line==null)
               {
               System.err.println("Not enough lines in "+args[optind]);
               }
           else
               {
               System.out.println(line);
               }
           ++optind;
           }
       return;
   }
}
```

It happens that the java program was much faster (~1'45'') to fetch a large index than the C program (~2'15'') on the same machine (I ran that test several times).

How can I explain that difference ?

Comment: Note: The buffersizes are not equal hence the programs do not do the "exact" same thing.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen - the code is not equivalent for more reasons than that :)

Comment: @Perception: True, but that was my first observation and seemed enough to point out that the programs are indeed not equal.

Comment: The C implementation has a 10Mb array instantiated on the process stack.  Does that really run?  Most processes have smaller stacks than that.

Comment: What C compiler are you using and what options are you passing? Be sure you are enabling all optimizations.

Comment: I started my C program with BUFSIZ. I've increased that value just to see if it would go faster.

Comment: @zr see the first comment for the C compilation.

Comment: Perhaps the compiler generates poor code on purpose because of the highly unorthodox coding style. That's what I would have done, had I been a compiler.

Comment: @Lundi: feel free to edit my code to correct the style.

Comment: @Pierre Coding style is somewhat subjective and I wouldn't want to derail your question into some coding style debate. Such things are better discussed at [Code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), where one can ask for feedback and improvements on working code.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The most likely explanation for the Java version to be faster than the C version is that the C version is incorrect.

After fixing the C version, I obtained the following results (contradicting your claim that Java is faster than C):

```
Java 1.7 -client: 65 milliseconds (after JVM warmed up)
Java 1.7 -server: 82 milliseconds (after JVM warmed up)
gcc -O3:          37 milliseconds
```

The task was to print the 200000-th line from file `words.gz`. File `words.gz` was generated by gzipping `/usr/share/dict/words`.

---

```
...
static char buffer[MY_BUFFER_SIZE];
...
ssize_t len;
while((len=gzread(in,buffer,MY_BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0  &&  curr<=index)
    {
    char* p=buffer;
    char* endp=buffer+len;
    while(p < endp)
       {
...
```

Comment: what did you change in the C version please ?

Comment: Thanks ! the first time I wrote my C code, I used gzgets instead of gzread but I didn't change the test in the loop over the buffer.

Comment: @Pierre: I see. If you rerun the benchmark on your computer with your files, is C faster than Java now?

Comment: Yes I did the test at work a few hours ago. But the difference was not as large as I expected.

Comment: for the record the standard java's gzip is inefficient.

Comment: @bestsss If Java's gzip *decompression* algorithm is translated line-by-line to C, how much faster would run compared to the original Java code?

Comment: @Atom, java's inflater impl. **is native** (zlib). The problem is: the default buffer is only 512 bytes, it's copied at least 2 times when read from the file, calling native code w/ byte[] usually involves 2 copies too, there are native calls 2 (FileInputStream and GZIPInputStream). Then CRC32 is also native - that's a HUGE blunder (another copies of byte[]) and  quite a performance hit, even replacing CRC32 w/ java boots perf. Overall the problem is in the way chaining of input streams in java works (intermediate buffers everywhere), that Inflater/Deflater dont allow a direct ByteBuffer.

Comment: @bestsss I am not sure I can believe your explanation is correct. When I run "gzip -t somefile.gz" on my notebook, I get throughput of about 15-24 MB/s. I presume that the native part of Java's zip decompression also runs at this speed. A memory copy, even with multiple intermediate buffers, is much faster than 15-24 MB/s - so chaining of input streams shouldn't be the main bottleneck. ... but I didn't analyse nor benchmark Java's zip implementation, so I may be wrong.

Comment: Can you include the timings for `-server` as this is the default?

Comment: @Atom The native x86 gzip code is that slow, that Azul could replace it with a Java solution that was faster (and could be much easier multi threaded). Whatever it's doing it's clearly not especially optimized. Note that I wouldn't write the java code in that way either, seems there are some improvements possible (though no idea how your final c code looks like)

Answer (score 15):

Because fputc() isn't very fast and you're adding stuf char-by-char in your output file.

calling fputc_unlocked or rather delimiting the stuff you want to add and call fwrite() should be faster.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. The author of the question did not specify the average length of a line in his GZIP files.

Comment: `fputc()` is only used for a single line after skipping a huge number of supposedly similar lines. Not the *inner loop* we should be looking for.  The huge automatic buffer is a better candidate.  Making it the same size as in java (2048) would allow for a fair comparison.

Answer (score 12):

Well your programs are doing different things. I didn't profile your program, but from looking at your code I suspect this difference:

For building the line, you use this in Java:

```
if(curr==this.index)
{
    if(line==null) line=new StringBuilder(500);
    line.append((char)buffer[i]);
}
```

And this in C:

```
if(curr==index)
{
    fputc(*p,stdout);
}
```

I.e. you're printing one character at a time to stdout. Which is buffere, by default, but I suspect it's still slower than the 500 character buffer you use in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have deeper knowledge about what optimizations the compiler performs, but I guess this what makes the difference between your programs. Microbenchmarks like this very, very, very hard to get right and meaningful. Here's an article by Brian Goetz that elaborates on this: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp02225/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Very large buffers can be slower.  I would suggest you make the buffer size the same. i.e. both 2 or 8 KB

Comment: I started using stdio: BUFSIZ : ~ same result

Comment: In C (zlib) the large buffer does not matter at all, in java it does since it's copied multiple times. You can use a memory mapped file, just as well. Java's FileInputStream is (was?) optimized for smaller buffers 2K in Win, 8K - linux, in that case uses the stack to allocate, otherwise it's malloc/free (and some malloc are much slower than stack), that's why the smaller buffer performs better. I had horrid crashes in native memory when calling in deeper recursion, double SIGSEG and the process is dead (the 2nd happens when attempting to write the crash log, hence no crash log event)